# Equations with alignment and with centering between alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
a'_{1,1} & a'_{1,2}\\
a'_{2,1} & a'_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} &&= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\alpha} & \sin{\alpha} \\
-\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{bmatrix}
&&\cdot
&&\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
&&\cdot
&&\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} \\
\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\textbf{A}' &&= \textbf{R}^T &&\cdot && \textbf{A} &&\cdot &&\textbf{R}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

It aligns indeed all the arguments like this:

[image]

But I want to have all the arguments centered between the separation as follows and without the equation numbering:

[image]

Comment: You can use `\underset` in order to get some letters/words underneath the matrices but it doesn't quite give the desired result. And for the equal sign it won't even stay in the same line as the letters

Comment: And of course you can always do it the manual, dirty way: Prepending `~` until the desired space is reached - or simply using `\hspace{}`. But that has to be adjusted every time the equation changes...

Comment: indeed @Mico. I remove `gather` from the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A seven column array does the job. The columns for `=` and `\cdot` are of type `>{{}}c<{{}}` so the spacing around the items is the expected one. The outer `array` has no intercolumn spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ @{}c *{3} { >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{} } }
\begin{bmatrix}
a'_{1,1} & a'_{1,2}\\
a'_{2,1} & a'_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
&=&
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\alpha} & \sin{\alpha} \\
-\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{bmatrix}
&\cdot&
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}
&\cdot&
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} \\
\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\[2ex]
\textbf{A}' &=& \textbf{R}^T &\cdot& \textbf{A} &\cdot &\textbf{R}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again @egreg. Could you please the use of `{ @{}c *{3} { >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{} } }`?

Comment: @ecjb `@{}` means “no intercolumn space at this point”. With `*{3}{...}` it is meant “repeat 3 times what comes in the second set of braces. As said in the answer, even numbered columns will be like `{}={}` so the spacing around the sign are correctly handled.

Comment: thank you @egreg, as it is still a little dense for me, do you have a link for the documentation about that notation? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @ecjb The `*{n}(...}` notation is documented in all main LaTeX manuals. For the prefixes and affixes `>{...}` and `<{...}` look at the manual of `array`: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/array.pdf

Comment: thank you again @egreg for the answer. I just tried the code again and `{ccccccc}` instead of `{ @{}c *{3} { >{{}}c<{{}} @{} c @{} } }` works also.

Comment: @ecjb If you accept wrong spacing…

Answer (score 5):

Here's a suggestion: Take a different approach to denoting what's `A'`, `A`, `R`, `R^T`, by using `\underbrace` directives. This should make it clear to even the most casual readers that they're not dealing with two separate equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  a'_{1,1} & a'_{1,2}\\
  a'_{2,1} & a'_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle\mathbf{A}'}} = 
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
   \cos{\alpha} & \sin{\alpha} \\
  -\sin{\alpha} & \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{bmatrix*}}_{\textstyle\mathbf{R}^T}}
\cdot
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}}_{\textstyle\mathbf{A}}}
\cdot
{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  \cos{\alpha} & -\sin{\alpha} \\
  \sin{\alpha} &  \cos{\alpha} \\
\end{bmatrix*}}_{\textstyle\mathbf{R}}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```